# Join many to one: combine related characteristics

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe where each row represents a spatial unit. The nbid* variables indicate which unit is a neighbour. I would like to get the *dum* variable of the neighbour into the main dataframe. (Instead of spatial units it could be any kind of relations within a dataframe - business partners, relatives, related genes etc.)
Some simplified data look like this:

```
seed(999)
df_base <- data.frame(id = seq(1:100),
                 dum= sample(c(rep(0,50), rep(1,50)),100),
                 nbid_1=sample(1:100,100),
                 nbid_2=sample(1:100,100),
                 nbid_3=sample(1:100,100)) %>% 
  mutate(nbid_1 =  replace(nbid_1, sample(row_number(), size = ceiling(0.1 * n()), replace = FALSE), NA),
         nbid_2 =  replace(nbid_2, sample(row_number(), size = ceiling(0.3 * n()), replace = FALSE), NA),
         nbid_3 =  replace(nbid_3, sample(row_number(), size = ceiling(0.7 * n()), replace = FALSE), NA))
```

(In these simplified data and other than in the real data, neighbours 1,2 and 3 can be the same, but that does not matter for the question.)

My approach was to duplicate and then join the data, which would look like this:

```
df1 <- df_base
df2 <- df_base %>% 
  select(-c(nbid_1,nbid_2,nbid_3)) %>% 
  rename(nbdum=dum)

df <- left_join(df1,df2,by=c("nbid_1"="id")) %>% 
  rename(nbdum1=nbdum) %>% 
  left_join(.,df2,by=c("nbid_2"="id")) %>% 
  rename(nbdum2=nbdum) %>% 
  left_join(.,df2,by=c("nbid_3"="id")) %>% 
  rename(nbdum3=nbdum)
```

*df* is the result that I am looking for - from here I can create an overall neighbour dummy or a count.
This approach is however neither elegant nor feasible to implement with the real data which has many more neighbours.

How can I solve this in a less clumsy way?

Thanks in advance for your ideas!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key clue is that when you see `var_1, var_2, ..., var_n`, it suggests that the data can be transformed to be longer. See `pivot_longer()` or `data.table::melt()` where `molten` data is discussed frequently.

For your example, we can pivot and then join the `df2` table back. I am unsure if the format is needed but after the join, we can pivot back to wide with `pivot_wider()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df1 %>%
  select(!id) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("nbid"), names_prefix = "nbid_")%>%
  mutate(original_id = rep(1:100, each = 3))%>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("value" = "id"))%>%
  pivot_wider(original_id, values_from = c(value, nbdum))

#> # A tibble: 100 × 7
#>    original_id value_1 value_2 value_3 nbdum_1 nbdum_2 nbdum_3
#>          <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1           1      25      90      23       0       0       1
#>  2           2      12      NA      NA       1      NA      NA
#>  3           3      11      40      47       0       0       0
#>  4           4      94      87      NA       0       1      NA
#>  5           5      46      77      NA       1       0      NA
#>  6           6      98      82      NA       1       0      NA
#>  7           7      43      NA      NA       1      NA      NA
#>  8           8      74      NA       7       0      NA       1
#>  9           9      57      NA      NA       1      NA      NA
#> 10          10      49      72      NA       0       0      NA
#> # … with 90 more rows

## compare to original

as_tibble(df)
#> # A tibble: 100 × 8
#>       id   dum nbid_1 nbid_2 nbid_3 nbdum1 nbdum2 nbdum3
#>    <int> <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1     0     25     90     23      0      0      1
#>  2     2     1     12     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
#>  3     3     1     11     40     47      0      0      0
#>  4     4     1     94     87     NA      0      1     NA
#>  5     5     0     46     77     NA      1      0     NA
#>  6     6     1     98     82     NA      1      0     NA
#>  7     7     1     43     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
#>  8     8     0     74     NA      7      0     NA      1
#>  9     9     0     57     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
#> 10    10     0     49     72     NA      0      0     NA
#> # … with 90 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

As you just seem to be indexing `dum` with your neighbor variables you should be able to do:

```
library(dplyr)

df_base %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("nbid"), ~ dum[.x], .names = "nbdum_{1:3}"))

     id dum nbid_1 nbid_2 nbid_3 nbdum1 nbdum2 nbdum3
1     1   0     25     90     23      0      0      1
2     2   1     12     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
3     3   1     11     40     47      0      0      0
4     4   1     94     87     NA      0      1     NA
5     5   0     46     77     NA      1      0     NA
6     6   1     98     82     NA      1      0     NA
7     7   1     43     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
8     8   0     74     NA      7      0     NA      1
9     9   0     57     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
10   10   0     49     72     NA      0      0     NA
...
```

Or same idea in base R:

```
df_base[paste0("nbdum", 1:3)] <- sapply(df_base[startsWith(names(df_base), "nbid")], \(x) df_base$dum[x])
```

Comment: Thank you Ritchie! This works perfectly when it is indeed indexing, i.e. when the ids correspond to the row number as in my sample data. For the real application the ids are more complex and do not correspond to the row number. I therefore accepted Cole's answer.